# Operand type clash: text is incompatible with uniqueidentifier

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pdo, zend-framework2

I've seen similar error messages, but most have to do with comparing `int` or `float` to `uniqueidenifier`, which makes sense why you'd get an error. My error is this:

> SQLSTATE[22018]: Invalid character value for cast specification: 206 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Operand type clash: text is incompatible with uniqueidentifier (SQLExecute[206] at /usr/src/php-5.4.8/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)

I'm building a PHP ZF2 application and attempting to call a user-defined function with parameters. The first four parameters are `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` values. The last four are `BIT` values. Here is my code:

```
public function getCustomerInspectionDocuments($fkCustomer) {
    /** @var \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet $result */
    $result = $adapter->query("
        SELECT
            createUser.FullName AS CreateUser,
            udf.CreateTime,
            udf.CompleteTime,
            modifyUser.FullName AS ModifyUser,
            udf.ModifyTime,
            udf.Source,
            udf.id AS InstanceID
        FROM
            udfDocumentInstances(
                :fkCustomer,
                :fkDocumentQueue,
                :fkDocumentType,
                :fkADUser,
                :Completed,
                :Deleted,
                :LinkByXXX,
                :LinkByOwnership
            ) udf
            LEFT JOIN ADUser createUser
                ON udf.fkCreateUser = createUser.pkid
            LEFT JOIN ADUser deleteUser
                ON udf.fkDeleteUser = deleteUser.pkid
            LEFT JOIN ADUser modifyUser
                ON udf.fkModifyUser = modifyUser.pkid
        ORDER BY
            ModifyTime DESC
    ", array(
        ':fkCustomer' => $fkCustomer,
        ':fkDocumentQueue' => '57B5829B-3EAE-46FF-8130-8A432176DE2A',
        ':fkDocumentType' => '7E5D5187-B38A-E211-B52D-0F1256A21434',
        ':fkADUser' => null,
        ':Completed' => null,
        ':Deleted' => 0,
        ':LinkByXXX' => 0,
        ':LinkByOwnership' => 0,
    ));

    // do some other stuff and return the records
}
```

This code works absolutely fine when executed against SQL Server 2012, but when I switch it back to 2008, it chokes with that error message. I'm using the same driver, so the only thing that changes is the server.

The problem seems to be a combination of the fact it's executed against a UDF and that I'm binding the parameters via PDO. If I change it to a simple `SELECT` query (from a normal table), it works. Or if I put the parameter values directly into the query, that also works. But I need to call this UDF, and I would prefer to use the parameterized query.

Is there a way to see exactly what is being sent to the SQL Server (i.e. the completely assembled query)? Or is it possible that it's passed to the server as a parameterized query and it's the SQL Server that's assembling it?

Comment: You should be able to use SQL Profiler to see what is arriving at the datbase.

Comment: @davek: Thanks. That helped me discover that the query is not assembled on the web server, but is passed to the SQL Server as a parameterized query. Looks like all the parameters are being passed as `TEXT` which is the problem (see my answer below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what I found out from SQL Profiler (thanks @davek), it looks like the query is assembled on the SQL Server side, and PDO is passing all of the parameters as `TEXT`, which cannot be implicitly converted to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` or `BIT`. I'm not sure how to get it to pass them as `CHAR` by default. I'm also not sure why it doesn't cause an issue when using a parameterized query with a normal table.

Here is the temporary workaround I've come up with. It's ugly, but it works for now. Hopefully someone else can come up with a better answer.

```
'...
FROM
    dbo.udfDocumentInstances(
        CAST(:fkCustomer AS CHAR(36)),
        CAST(:fkDocumentQueue AS CHAR(36)),
        CAST(:fkDocumentType AS CHAR(36)),
        CAST(:fkADUser AS CHAR(36)),
        CAST(:Completed AS CHAR(1)),
        CAST(:Deleted AS CHAR(1)),
        CAST(:LinkByDEA AS CHAR(1)),
        CAST(:LinkByOwnership AS CHAR(1))
    ) udf
...'
```

So I'm casting the values from `TEXT` to `CHAR`, and then the SQL Server will implicitly convert them to `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` or `BIT`.

If anyone can come up with a way to pass them as `CHAR` instead of `TEXT`, without having to explicitly cast each one, please post your response.